# YII framework Long url parameter issue

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii framework. I am using some third party API to access from the following url

**`http://development.example.com/projectname/join/login`**

After accessing that API, It will redirect to the following url

```
http://development.example.com/projectname/join/login?jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI1YmE0Nzc2NjM5NmNmOTI2NjYzNDk0NGExYWEzYjIwNSIsImlhdCI6MTM5ODI0ODcyMCwiZW1haWwiOiJrYXZ5YS5ickBzb2Z0d2F5c29sdXRpb25zLm5ldCIsIm5hbWUiOiJLYXZ5YSIsImxuYW1lIjoiUHJpeWEifQ.rvhVSf6Ot1gK6VxMZWNBxPI4c6MCL4YqLzc74lx6k9U&r=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopment.example.com%2Fprojectname%2Fadd%2Ffollow
```

The Problem is it contains lot of parameters more than 400 characters. so its throwing error "requested page can't be displayed. "

So In YII framework where can Set up to allow maximum parameter

Comment: Most likely this is due to the used API, but without more information this is very difficult to determine.

Comment: @Michiel found the problem.. The reason is URL contains "r" so only its not working